# AWS CloudFormation Fn::Join - escape single quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, escaping, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I would like to escape single quotes such that they are part of the string. From something like this:

```
!Join [ '', [ 'xyz', '.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', ''', ',', ' '' 'something' ] ]
```

I would to get this:

```
xyz.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'something
```

I use it for the serverless framework as an environmental variable, which treats it as a straing such that it puts two more single quotes around it.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes and escpaing the single ones like this `"\'xyz"` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused on your Join statement, but you can include single quotes by enclosing them in double quotes (no need to escape). You also need to wrap your commas in double quotes. From the Serverless documentation:

> Passing the Cache-Control header as "'max-age=120'" means API Gateway will receive the value as 'max-age=120' (enclosed with single quotes).
>
> In .yml, strings containing :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, @, ` must be quoted.

So to produce `xyz.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', 'something`, you can use the following Join statement:

```
!Join [ 
  "", [
    "xyz", 
    ".execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
    "', '",
    "something" 
  ] 
]
```

*Disclaimer*: I am not exactly sure what you want your output string to be, but this demonstrates the general concept.

---

For those not writing this in JSON, you can use the intrinsic `Fn::Join` function in your serverless.yml file for a more comprehensive structure:

```
sameWeirdEndpoint:
  Fn::Join:
    - ""
    - - "xyz"
      - ".execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
      - "', '"
      - "something"
```

Hope this helps!

Reference: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#custom-request-templates